# Update only the parameters of BatchNormalization layer in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

Is there a way to update only the parameters of the BatchNormalization layers in my model without training? (without changing the weights)

Comment: Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45420579/10878733) answer.

Comment: I don't understand how this link can help me. It explains what batch normalization is.